# On edit button click show the row data in input text field and update the new values in the same row in React js

Tags: html, reactjs, crud

I am new to react js and i am designing form where user enters name and on add button click the data is showed in table.On edit button the data of selected row should be showed in input of form and update the values on add button click. i am unable to code the logic for the same .It would be of great help if anyone would provide solution for the update operation.Below is my coding

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Table from './Table';
import Form from './Form';
import './App.css';

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            id: 1,
            firstname: '',
            items: []
        }
    };
 handleFormSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        let items = [...this.state.items];

        items.push({
            id: this.state.id,
            firstname: this.state.firstname,

        });

        this.setState({
            items,
            id: this.state.id + 1,
            firstname: '',

        });
    };
  handleInputChange = (e) => {
        let input = e.target;
        let name = e.target.name;
        let value = input.value;

        this.setState({
            [name]: value
        })
    };
 render() {
        return ( 
        <div className = "App" >
            <Form handleFormSubmit = { this.handleFormSubmit }
            handleInputChange = { this.handleInputChange }
            newId = { this.state.id }
            newFirstname = { this.state.firstname }/> 
            <Table items = { this.state.items }/> 
        </div >
        );
    }
}
export default App;
```

Table.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
class Table extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const items = this.props.items;
        return (
            <div id = "Table" >
            <table class = "tdgreeting" border = "1" frame = "void" rules = "rows" >
            <tbody >
            <tr >
            <th > Id < /th> 
            <th > FirstName < /th>
            <th > Edit < /th>

            < /tr >
            {
                items.map(item => {
                    return (
                        <tr >    
                        <td > { item.id } < /td>
                        <td > { item.firstname} < /td>
                        <td > < button class = "btnStyle" onClick = { this.props.onUpdate } > Edit < /button></td >         
                        </tr>
                    );
                })
            } 
            </tbody>
            </table>
            </div>       
        );
    }
}
export default Table;
```

Form.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
class Form extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return ( 
        <div class = "main" > 
        <h3 > Greetings < /h3>   
        <form id = "formInput" onSubmit = { this.props.handleFormSubmit } >
            <input id = "firstname"
            value = { this.props.newFirstname }
            type = "firstname"
            name = "firstname"
            placeholder = "Firstname"
            onChange = { this.props.handleInputChange }
            required / >
            <button type = "submit"
            value = "Submit" > Save < /button>
            <button type = "reset"
            value = "Reset" > Cancel < /button> 
            < /form > 
            < /div >
        );
    }
}

export default Form;
```

Comment: You can use Formikjs library. That will make your work more easy. Let me know if you need more help. 
https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/overview

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve what you mentioned in the question. The whole code could be refactored a lot if you're using `Hooks` since that is beyond the scope of this question, we can update our class-based component.

I added a new `onUpdate` function handler which receives the `edited` name from the `Table` component and updates your existing `items` state with the matching `id` received from the `Table` Component.

Here is a working [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-answer-60873116-bo1du?file=/src/components/Table.js).

```
//App.js
import React from "react";
import Table from "./Table";
import Form from "./Form";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      id: 1,
      firstname: "",
      items: [],
    };
  }

  handleFormSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    let items = [...this.state.items];

    items.push({
      id: this.state.id,
      firstname: this.state.firstname,
    });

    this.setState({
      items,
      id: this.state.id + 1,
      firstname: "",
    });
  };

  handleInputChange = (e) => {
    let input = e.target;
    let name = e.target.name;
    let value = input.value;

    this.setState({
      [name]: value,
    });
  };

  onUpdate = (item) => {
    const updatedData = this.state.items.map((x) =>
      x.id === item.id ? { ...x, firstname: item.newFirstname } : x
    );
    this.setState({ items: updatedData });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Form
          handleFormSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit}
          handleInputChange={this.handleInputChange}
          newId={this.state.id}
          newFirstname={this.state.firstname}
        />
        <Table items={this.state.items} onUpdate={this.onUpdate} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

Added a separate `form-inputs` in your `Table` component to avoid it being tightly coupled with your `App.js` file. Of course, you could refactor this a lot using `hooks` and with proper usage of components.

```
//Table.js
import React from "react";
import Form from "./Form";

class Table extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isEdit: false,
    newFirstname: "",
    id: "",
  };

  updateItem = (item) => {
    this.setState({ isEdit: true, id: item.id });
  };

  handleInputChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ newFirstname: e.target.value });
  };

  handleFormSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.onUpdate(this.state);
    this.setState({ isEdit: false });
  };

  render() {
    const items = this.props.items;

    return (
      <div id="Table">
        <table class="tdgreeting" border="1" frame="void" rules="rows">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th> Id </th>
              <th> FirstName </th>
              <th> Edit </th>
            </tr>
            {items.map((item) => {
              return (
                <tr>
                  <td> {item.id} </td>
                  <td> {item.firstname} </td>
                  <td>
                    {" "}
                    <button
                      class="btnStyle"
                      onClick={() => this.updateItem(item)}
                    >
                      {" "}
                      Edit{" "}
                    </button>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              );
            })}
          </tbody>
        </table>
        {this.state.isEdit ? (
          <Form
            handleFormSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit}
            handleInputChange={this.handleInputChange}
           />
        ) : null}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Table;
```